# Serializing a BigInteger

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, biginteger

Is there any method of serializing a BigInteger to and from an XML file?

Below is a short snippet that demonstrates how I'm currently serializing classes:

```
static public void SerializeToXML( Report report )
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( Report ) );
    using ( TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter( Path.Combine( report.Path, report.Filename ) ) )
    {
        serializer.Serialize( textWriter, report );
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Report
{
    public BigInteger CurrentMaximum { get; set; }
}
```

All other properties within the Report class get serialized correctly, however, the BigInteger properties do not. Is there a way to serialize this property?

Comment: FYI I experimented with `TypeConverter` and due the to requirement that types are supported by XML Schema; `XmlSerializer` does not support it (by design).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `XmlSerializer` is designed to create XML describeable using a standard XML Schema; that were in the framework during the .Net 1.0 phase (which means [xs:integer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#integer) isn't supported).

**IXmlSerializable**

You will need to modify the `BigInteger` class and add the `IXmlSerializable` interface to it. If you need to use XSD round-tripping (e.g. WebService references) this might cause problems.

```
public class BigInteger : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Value;

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        // You should really a create schema for this.
        // Hardcoded is fine.
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        Value = int.Parse(reader.ReadString());
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Proxy Property** *(Although this looks like it has code-smell it is way more portable)*

Create a new property with a supported schema type (most probably xs:string) and hide it from intellisense.

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class SerializePlease
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public BigInteger BigIntValue;

    [XmlElement("BigIntValue")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string BigIntValueProxy
    {
        get
        {
            return BigIntValue.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            BigIntValue = BigInteger.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the IXmlSerializable interface. Rather then messing with the BigInteger class, I implemented the IXmlSerializable interface within the Report class. This way I'm managing the whole serialization of the class.

Comment: The XSD specification does have a true integer type – [`integer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#integer); it is derived from XSD's "BigRational" type [`decimal`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#decimal) that supports the complete (mathematical) set of rationals.  (It also has `int` and `long` for 32 and 64 bit signed types that map to the common computer types.)

Comment: Interesting (considering I was quoting Microsoft there), in which case the BigInteger class is probably the best place to implement IXmlSerializable.

Comment: IMO the cause of the problem is that the XmlSerializer is badly designed. And decent serializer needs to support non intrusive extension points. Mixing serialization into the class you want to serialize is ugly IMO.

Comment: But unfortunately we need to deal with it. There are a few third-party XmlSerializers that are supposed to be better, but they are not free and I am not sure if they can cope with this type of problem.